# Libraries for Algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, sdk

Are there any libraries/sdk/etc that 'allow' to use algorithms in your programs without any difficulty? The following code may describe my question better(I need something like this):

```
algorithm* a = new search_algorithm("binary_search");
a->set_data("some text to be searched");
search_result_t r = a->search("this_text");
```

Thanks for response.

P.S. Thanks all, but I've "heard" about the STL and Boost. I used a simple example above, but "in my dreams" I want to get this, too:

```
algorithm* a = new search_algorithm("boyer_moore");
//...
a = new graph_algorithm("brent");
a->set_graph(/*graph_t*/gt);
a->detect_cycles(...);
```

or even this:

```
a = new tree_algorithm("kruskal");
tree_t* mt = new tree_t(...);
a->set_tree(mt);
a->get_min_spanning_tree(...);
```

Comment: yes.. that's what SDKs are for.... Just search for one according to the algorithm you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've 'heard' of Boost and STL_, so I assume you've heard of

- [boyer-moore](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/xpressive/detail/utility/boyer_moore.hpp),
- [min spanning tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/graph/doc/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.html),
- [Brent's algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/toolkit/internals1/minima.html)

What is it, exactly, that you are missing?

Comment: Maybe the library API syntax? I would like to set only the algorithm name and get corresponding functionality. Hope, I would be able to describe my question better as soon as possible. Thanks for [useful] links.

Comment: Erm... thanks for the accept. The API library syntax... I guess what the rest of us do, is mould our own interfaces on top of them, so we can use GreatCodeWrittenByOthers(TM) without having to think/adjust our preferred coding styles for using it. There is a limit what FOSS can deliver for you :)

Comment: Do you know does Boost covers the all algorithms(the ones listed in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms)?

Comment: Well, for one thing I know Strassen's (matrix mult) is still a TODO, so the real quick answer should be: no

Answer (score 2):

you can use the 'STL: algorithms' and the boost library. It doesn't always contain what you are looking for but that is because a lot of stuff has to be custom made for your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library already includes templates for a number of algorithms (including binary search). With the minor proviso that a binary search won't work in the example you've given (it requires sorted input), it's actually even easier than you've shown:

```
int values[] = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9};

int *pos = std::lower_bound(values, values+6, 5);
```